# C static variable not updating

Tags: c, variables, static

I'm having a problem with my C code where I declare a static int variable (as a flag), then initialize it to -1 in init() which is only called once, then when I try to update the value to 0 or 1 later on, it keeps reverting back to -1.

Does anyone know what the problem can be?

I don't have any local variables with the same identifier so I'm really lost.

Thanks!

```
static int previousState;

void init()
{
   previousState = -1;
}

void moveForward(int currentState)
{
    if (previousState == -1)
        previousState = currentState;

    if (previousState != currentState)
    {
        /* do stuff */
        /* PROBLEM: it never goes into here, because previousState is always -1! */
    }

    /* other code */
}

void main()
{
   init();

   if (fork() == 0)
   {
        /* do stuff */
        moveForward(1);
        exit();
   }

   /* more forks */

   moveForward(0);
   exit();
}
```

Comment: what's passed to `moveForward()` function?

Comment: depending on the state, either a 0 or 1.

Comment: Either you call init more than you think, or you call this function with -1. Debugger or debug prints will tell you...

Comment: You are either calling <code>init()</code> more than once or you are calling <code>moveForward()</code> with your argument as <code>-1</code>. If you do not post your calling code, I can't tell what the problem could be.

Comment: I smell a `=` instead of `==` in the `/* other code */` block

Comment: @lc. other than the places I put in my sample code, this variable is not used. And that was my first guess. =P haha.

Comment: I posted some code from the main method and I have print statements in my method so I can verify that init() only gets called once. Thanks!

Comment: You understand that the children and parent don't share the same memory, correct?

Comment: @Duck I guess I didn't, but now I know. thanks a lot! =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each process calls moveForward just once. Processes do not share static data!

Use threads, or use shared memory. Also use mutex or semaphore for concurrent access of shared data . Preferably switch to a language better suited for parallel prosessing...

Comment: that would make a lot of sense.

Comment: thanks, hyde! yeah, we're supposed to use semaphores, but only when the states are different so I was trying to keep a flag to see when I would need one.. haha. I guess I need to think of a different solution. thanks a lot! =]